# Datepicker with week number and days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker that shows the week of the year.

What I would like to do is enable the week number, so the user can choose the week number or the day.

Example: one user picked the week 32, and other user picked 08/08/2016.

HTML code:

```
<label>Select Week</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="weekPicker">
```

Script code:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     showWeek: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     maxDate: 'today'  
  });
});
```

Working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/iandrabedin/jhducskr/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746358/select-week-number-or-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an event handler to the week numbers in the `beforeShow` handler will do that

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    maxDate: 'today',
    beforeShow: function(elem, ui) {
      $(ui.dpDiv).on('click', 'tbody .ui-datepicker-week-col', function() {
       $(elem).val('Week ' + $(this).text()).datepicker( "hide" );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker table tbody .ui-datepicker-week-col {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Click week numbers to select weeks, dates to select dates etc.</p>

<label>Select Week</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="weekPicker">
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works great! But what if I have two datepickers?

Comment: If I select one week on the first datepicker, and then a different week on the second datepicker, the first one changes again. What I would like to do, as an example, is from week 30 to week 32, like a range of weeks. So it would be like:  Select Week : Week 30. Select Something else : Week 32.

Comment: @IandraBedin - indeed it does, unbinding the event on close should solve that -> **https://jsfiddle.net/deunrjkv/1/**